# How XCode knows about name of function at compile time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, selector, compile-time

I have written simple code to practice `selector` in Objective C, which is working fine

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B", nil];
NSLog(@"Before adding %@",array);

SEL message = @selector(addObject:); //I will change this line

if([array respondsToSelector:message])
{
    [array performSelector:message withObject:@"C"];
}

NSLog(@"After adding %@",array);
```

But as soon as I change selector line to,

```
SEL message = @selector(addobject:);// Just changed name of selector
```

XCode starts giving warning :

> Undeclared selector 'addobject:'

Now, question is how XCode knows at compile time about name of method is correct or not. Is there always list of selector generates internally for whatever object I am creating? In this case for `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Xcode knows is that there is no class, either in the system code or in your program, that declares a selector called `addobject`.  You can prove this by creating a custom class that declares an `addobject` method, and the warning should go away, but of course the program will crash with a `unrecognized selector sent to object` error message.

Comment: That is what my question is, all time XCode keeps track about all the messages?

Comment: Yes, Xcode has a precompiled header that contains all of the method names for the system classes, and it keep track of all of the method names that are defined in your program.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Waiting for SO to allow me accept your answer.

Comment: @pranitkothari: XCode doesn't need to keep track of all selectors everywhere. It just checks whether that selector exists *in the declarations that are visible from that point in the code* (i.e. from the headers that are imported (and from the headers that are imported from those headers, etc.)). Remember, source files in C can be compiled separately. What you do in other source files do not affect this source file. In order to not have this warning, there must be some class or protocol declaration containing a method with this selector, in this file or something it imports.

Comment: @newacct So, there is no precompiled headers with all names of system classes and method exists as suggested by user3386109. Thanks for reply.